# preg_match to show lines containing one string and one of the other two

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've got an array in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sth!Man!Tree!null
    [1] => sth!Maning!AppTree!null
    [2] => sth!Man!Lake!null
    [3] => sth!Man!Tree!null
    [4] => sth!Man!AppTree!null
    [5] => sth!Maning!AppTree!null
    [6] => sth!Man!Tree!null
    [7] => sth!Maning!AppTree!null
    [8] => sth!Maning!AppTree!null
    [9] => sth!Man!Tree!null
   [10] => sth!Man!Tree!null
   [11] => sth!Man!Tree!null
   [12] => sth!Man!Tree!null
   [12] => sth!Man!Lake!null
   [13] => sth!Maning!Tree!null
)
```

and this preg_match function:

```
preg_match("/Man/i", $line) && (preg_match("/!Tree!/i", $line) || preg_match("/!Lake!/i", $line))
```

My goal is to change it to one preg_match regex function to display only lines with Man and Tree or Man and Lake. Is it possible?

Comment: I would use `preg_grep()` instead of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match("/Man!(?:Tree|Lake)/i", $line, $matches)` should do it most efficiently.

Comment: What if you have `sth!Lake!Man!null`? This solution is less universal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?i)\b(?:Lake|Tree)\b.*\bMan\b|\bMan\b.*\b(?:Tree|Lake)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hF3lX7/3).

The word boundaries match only the whole words, `(?i)` inline mode option enables case-insensitive search, and we need at least two main alternatives to account for different positions of `Man` and `Lake`/`Tree`.

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?i)\\b(?:Lake|Tree)\\b.*\\bMan\\b|\\bMan\\b.*\\b(?:Tree|Lake)\\b/"; 
$str = " Man and Tree or Man and Lake. Is it possible?"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, however it looks not easy to be modified.

Comment: Please describe what modifications you intend to implement. I will try to explain.

Comment: It might be hard to use more words in your example. Do you think it can be done without concerning about the word positions?

Comment: If you have a list of the words, the regex can be built dynamically. Perhaps, you should not use a regex approach. Split by the exclamation mark, check the parts against your list.